# "ApexUnexpectedException" and Internal Server Error

Tags: eventlogfile

"ApexUnexpectedException" event type was introduced in Spring'19 release. Any idea if it captures the apex stacktrace whenever "Internal Server Error" happens?

Comment: this would be easily amenable to experimentation - just create a class that does an infinite loop and then execute anonymous; or a class that builds a giant heap